# Android Listener working in activity but not in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listadapter

I have an activity and two fragments. Im trying to get a clicked item from an arraylist. In my fragmentA I have a interface:

```
public interface GroupListener {
        public String onGroupSelected(String groupName);
}
```

and

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            groupListener = (GroupListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e)
        { 
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement the interface" +
                    "called GroupListener!");
        }
    }
```

This gets the postion from an item clicked in a list :

```
    public void onListItemClick(@NonNull ListView l, @NonNull View v, int position, long id) {
        groupListener.onGroupSelected((String) getListAdapter().getItem(position));
    }
```

I then have the listner in my activity and in fragmentB which looks the same:

```
   @Override
    public String onGroupSelected(String groupName) {
        System.out.println("in onGroup  in Activity");
        return groupName;
    }
```

```
   @Override
    public String onGroupSelected(String groupName) {
        System.out.println("in onGroup  in fragmentB");
        return groupName;
    }
```

But when i click an item only the listener in my activity is activated, not the one in my fragment. What is it that im missing?

Comment: can you please add the code where are you calling this functions..

Comment: I dont really understand, shoudnt they be called when i click on a group in my list? Im sorry im new to programming.

Comment: Adding the activity and the fragment code would help.

Answer (score 0):

The one in `FragmentB` will not fire, since you are only communicating with the activity from fragment A.

In your activity do something like this:

```
Override
    public String onGroupSelected(String groupName) {
        System.out.println("in onGroup  in Activity");
        FragmentB frag = //find your fragment using fragment manager
        frag.onGroupSelected(groupName);
        return groupName;
    }
```

This is how you call methods inside fragment from an activity

Answer (score 0):

It is a little late to answer but I found a way that works for me.
As listener will first get by activity, you can define destination fragment in the Main activity and then call a method in the destination fragment and do what you want:
In the main Activity listener

```
DestinationFragment fragment = (DestinationFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.destination_fragment);
fragment.sampleListener(bundle);
```

In the destination fragment define sampleListener and write your code.